# Count matches between two columns

Tags: excel

In Excel, I have two columns. One is a prediction, one is the result. I want to count how many times the prediction matches the result (i.e. a correct prediction).

The data is like so:

```
Col A      Col B
Bears      Bears
Chiefs     Raiders
Chargers   Chargers
Colts      Texans
Lions
Packers
```

So the number I want to get to via a formula is **2**, since that's how many matches there were (Bears and Chargers). Keep in mind the match has to be in the **same row**.

Thanks.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--(A1:A6=B1:B6))
```

The double negative will convert the TRUEs and FALSEs to 1s and 0s, respectively, then sum them up.

Comment: How can we ignore empty cells?

Comment: `=SUMPRODUCT((A1:A6=B1:B6)*(LEN(A1:A6)>0))`

Answer (score 3):

```
=SUMPRODUCT((A1:A6=B1:B6)*1)
```

The array equality expression will produce `{TRUE,FALSE,TRUE,FALSE,FALSE,FALSE}`
so you have an intermediate expression of `=SUMPRODUCT(({TRUE,FALSE,TRUE,FALSE,FALSE,FALSE})*1)`
since `TRUE*1=1`, that gets you `=SUMPRODUCT({1,0,1,0,0,0})` which gets you `2`.

Not any better than Dick's answer, but the "times 1" thing is easier for me to remember.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know of any formula that does exactly what you propose. The solution I have always used in this situation is to add a "Col C" that tests the row. Something to the effect of "=A2=B2" (in cell C2). You can then use countif ("=COUNTIF(C2:C4, TRUE)") the column to get the count you are looking for.