# How to count occurrences comparing with other range in google spreadsheets

Tags: google-sheets, google-drive-api

I have the result of a multiple choice exam, I want have the percentage of correct responses.
I have the responses in column B and the correct responses in column Z.

I've tried with countif but couldn't get what i need.

I want something like CountIf(B1:B40,Z1:Z4), so if B4 = Z4 then count. this should give me the amount of correct answers which then I can obtain the %..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way:

`=SUMPRODUCT((B:B=Z:Z)*(LEN(B:B)>0))`

Comment: Hiya, this may well solve the problem... but it'd be good if you could edit your answer and provide a little explanation about how and why it works :) Don't forget - there are heaps of newbies on Stack overflow, and they could learn a thing or two from your expertise - what's obvious to you might not be so to them.

Comment: agree with Taryn, now I've tried what you said, but it didn't work. it says Error: Circular dependency detected.
I assume you're trying to do if B=Z = 1 x 1 if B size >0 ??

Comment: ok, I've added a range and worked e.g B1:B40=Z1:Z40.  here's a nice explanation of how it works: http://stackoverflow.com/a/16288475/2517007