# Count matching values in 2 columns

Tags: excel

How can I count matching values in 2 columns?

I've tried using this formula: `=SUMPRODUCT(--(B1:B5=C1:C3))`

[image]

But I'm having #N/A. I should get a value 3.

Answer (score 3):

Try the following:

```
=SUMPRODUCT((COUNTIF(B1:B5,C1:C3)>0)+0)
```

Adapted from [@BarryHoudini](https://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/536087-count-if-values-one-range-appear-another.html)

It would count the total of exact value, base on lookup column.

Answer (score 1):

For the answer how to get your result you can check QHarr's answer.

Now on your error.

**First**: If you want the formula to work, you need the two ranges to have the same length so it should be: `=SUMPRODUCT(--(B1:B5=C1:C5))` and not `C1:C3`

**Second:** I guess you found your formula from the question: [Count matches between two columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7558718/count-matches-between-two-columns).
However, there is a main difference between your two sets of data.

In this question the same words are on the same row, in yours, only the a is on the same row on both columns. The point of the formula the way you wrote it, is to find the matches between the two columns ***according to their row number***. So the result you should get with this formula will be 1.