# How can I get Excel to count the number of cells in column P that are equal to the corresponding value in column O?

Tags: excel

`=SUMIF(P2:P125,COUNTIF(P2,"="&$O2),$Y2:$Y125)` isn't the solution, it seems.

Comment: The title of your question suggests that all you need is a `COUNTIF`, the formula you provide that you need more than that. This would be easier if you could [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/53694262/edit) to give us some sample data and the expected result

Comment: Originally I had tried "COUNTIF(P2:P125,"="&$O2)" to no avail. That's why I switched to SUMIF. still didn't work though!

Answer (score 0):

I found [this link](https://exceljet.net/formula/count-matches-between-two-columns) using the keywords "excel count matches between columns". The formula it lists is =SUMPRODUCT(--(range = range)). So if you have a fixed range you could try

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--(P2:P20=O2:O20))
```

where you can adjust the range to the cells you want.

If your data is a little more sparse, you can use an idea from a comment to [an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7559804/3503611) to a very similar question. The idea is to ignore blank cells with LEN(P:P)>0.

```
=SUMPRODUCT((O:O=P:P)*(LEN(O:O)>0)*(LEN(P:P)>0))
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you just mean the following:

```
=Countif($P$2:$P$125,O2)
```

then drag down.

In your provided code, I don't understand where the Y column comes in. As others have suggested, more context would be useful here.

Comment: Perhaps the code I tried was incorrect, and that's why it failed. Anyways, I just want the total number of values in this column P that are equal, for example if O4 and P4 are both "C" then I want that to count as 1 whereas if they were "B" and "N" then don't count towards the total (a '0'). For reference, the range I'm looking in is P2:P125 and I want that count to be displayed in the cell, P126.